# multiple plotting in R

Tags: r, plot

Dear stackoverflow users,

I need to produce a graph combining multiple plots that are already "complex" plots.I produce a graph with `plot()` and then I add an horizontal boxplots within the graph. The problem is that I need to reproduce this 12 times and keep this in the same figure.

```
# Example with only 2 plots: 

par(mfrow=c(1,2)) # Works for simple plots... but not here

#First plot
par(fig=c(0,1,0,1), new=FALSE)
plot(rnorm(100))  # Basic plot

par(fig=c(0,1,0,0.5), new=TRUE)
boxplot(rnorm(100), horizontal=TRUE, axes=FALSE) # Boxplot below

# Second plot
par(fig=c(0,1,0,1), new=FALSE)
plot(rnorm(100))

par(fig=c(0,1,0,0.5), new=TRUE)
boxplot(rnorm(100), horizontal=TRUE, axes=FALSE)

# end
```

Usually I would do it with `par(mfrow=c(3,4))` but in this case as there are already several plots involved it is not working and I can't find how to solve this! Moreover it is not clear for me how to deal with these `new=FALSE`or `new=TRUE`...
Any help would be very welcome!! :o)
In advance thank you very much!!

Jnop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear on whether you want to put the boxplot inside the xy plot or below the xy plot.  Assuming it's below, you could use mfrow and mfg to position the four plots as follows.

## solution using mfrow and mfg

```
# Example with only 2 plots: 
plot.new()
par(mfrow=c(2,2)) 
#First plot
par(mfg=c(1,1))
plot(rnorm(100))  # Basic plot
par(mfg=c(2,1) )
boxplot(rnorm(100), horizontal=TRUE, axes=FALSE) # Boxplot below
# Second plot
par(mfg=c(1,2) )
plot(rnorm(100))
par(mfg=c(2,2) )
boxplot(rnorm(100), horizontal=TRUE, axes=FALSE)
# end
```

If you want the boxplots to be smaller than the xy plots, you could use layout as follows:

```
#  Solution using layout
#First plot
plot.new()
#  define 3 rows; allocate xy plot to first 2 rows and boxplot to last row 
layout( matrix(c(1,1, 2, 3, 3, 4), nrow=3, ncol=2) )
 plot(rnorm(100))  # Basic plot
boxplot(rnorm(100), horizontal=TRUE, axes=FALSE) # Boxplot below
# Second plot
plot(rnorm(100))
boxplot(rnorm(100), horizontal=TRUE, axes=FALSE)
# end
```

The layout plots would look like:

[image]

A similar approach could be used with the boxplots inside the xy plots.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! The idea was really to keep the boxplots inside the xy plot and positioned close to the x axis but with my solution I was able to do 1 plot (xy + box) but I couldn't have multiple graphs... like with `par(mfr.( ))`. I tried  `mfg` and I was able to put the boxplots within the xy plot but then I couldn't change the position of the box... that should be on the lower part of the xy plot.

Comment: When boxplot ( or any plot) is added to an existing plot, it uses the coordinates of the existing plot to position its data.  By default, boxplot places it's boxes at integer positions starting with 1.  Since you are making horizontal boxes, the box appears at 1 on your y axis. The  boxplot function has the  at   parameter which specifies where the boxes should appear. To have the box appear in the lower part of your plot, you could set     at = -1  in the call to boxplot.

Comment: Finally it worked! Thank you very much!! I used `par(mfg=c(1,1) )` to put the boxplot on the same place than the xy plot and changed the position of the box using `at= ...`